# How to Show Custom Post on Pages Using PHP and Without a Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type using PHP below:

```
  // Product Custom Post Type
  function product_init() {
      // set up product labels
      $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Products',
    'singular_name' => 'Product',
    'add_new' => 'Add New Product',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
    'new_item' => 'New Product',
    'all_items' => 'All Products',
    'view_item' => 'View Product',
    'search_items' => 'Search Products',
    'not_found' =>  'No Products Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Products',
);

// register post type
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-randomize',
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'page-attributes'
    )
   );
      register_post_type( 'product', $args );

     // register taxonomy
     register_taxonomy('product_category', 'product', array('hierarchical' 
     => true, 'label' => 'Category', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => 
  array( 
  'slug' => 'product-category' )));
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'product_init' );
```

Now, I am wondering how can I **show Products** from the products category on the home page, about page, (enter static page here) without using a plugin and using PHP?

I have tried doing this using query var before and it just wasn't showing.

Comment: Where did you put this code, in your template? Wouldn't it be easier to just create a plugin yourself and then enable that plugin on your website. It is not required to publish it for others to use or something like that. Your entire plugin can be written in PHP. 

You can create a custom shortcode to elaborate all your custom posts on the home page, depending on what you want to do. You might as well just use the default posts page.

Comment: Thanks, trying to learn it the old fashioned way first. I figured you could accomplish this using a plugin and shortcodes